# How to requestFocus editText on recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-softkeyboard

I'm Implementing a `RecyclerView` which each column contains an `EditText` to enter a number. when I enter the number and click on the next button on the keyboard cursor should go to the next `EditText` and it should be focus. My problem is how to call `requestFocus()` function inside an adaptor which only having one EditText

[image]

given below is my adaptor function inside the bindview

```
 outstandingItemRowHolder.adviceNote.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) POReceiptDetailsFragment.poReceiptDetailsFragment.getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);

                        if(POReceiptDetailsFragment.poReceiptDetailsFragment != null){
                            //function to go to the next edittext???
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Can anyone tell me how to go to next editText box when click the soft keyboard next button?

Comment: Where on the keyboard is next button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the enter pressed key use this code

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    && event.getKeyCode() ==       KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
            {
                Log.i("event", "captured");

                return false;
            } 

        return false;
    }
});
```

and when the enter is pressed you can change the focus to the next row , for that you have to pass the recyclerview to the adapter liek this

```
   public CheckoutRecyclerviewAdapter(Context context, 
    CartItems cartItems,Recyclerview recyclerview) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cartItems = cartItems;
    this.recyclerview = recyclerview
}
```

after that you have to scroll the position to the next item  from this code

```
if(position<size+1{recyclerview.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(thisposition+1)}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the next item position available, then i think

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)
```

will change focus to the item at that position and hence the children should also get focus.

PS: this isn't tested